# Is there any way to unregister an event listener based on Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-listener

Actually I am trying to unregister Click event from an element based on particular Javascript file name.

By the way, the specified js file is a third party js file used for data analytics like no of clicks, page visits etc. Customer configures the functionality of this JS file in this JS's site.

When user loads the page, this js will be loaded. Our site is Single Page Application. I have to restrict this JS functionality in few pages for security reasons. I am not loading in those pages but since it is SPA, the cached JS file is able to perform it's functionality.

Unloading from Cache isn't possible. So the only option left for me is to un-register those events in sensitive pages.

I am able to do it manually from chrome developer console by deleting blur event (just example) in Event Listeners section of Elements tab.

[image]

So there should be a way to achieve it programmatically.

So could anyone please help me?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. You either need to block that file from loading and registering the event handler in the first place, or you need to use the module's API to unregister the handler (which might not be possible, but we can't tell you more without further details).

Comment: Thanks for ur time and answer. Now I cant block the file from loading. JS file is needed in multiple pages. Generally end user will set configurations in separate site which will load their js file in site. But I have to restrict in few pages even the end user configures in those pages for security purpose.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the particular code that you need to disable?

Comment: Do you have any control over the file that is loaded? To what extent is "user configuration" possible? What exactly is insecure about the event handler that needs to be disabled in crucial places?

Comment: Basically js file is for analytic purpose. Our site is a shopping portal. Merchandiser will configure click events, page visits etc. When end user opens our site, this js will get page from our site and appends events to elements and renders on end user's screen. We dont have control on this js file as it is third party. We either need to unload/restrict this js in few pages or unregister events in those pages.

Comment: Yes, you should just not include that script in the sensitive pages. Un-loading or un-registering is not possible in general after an untrusted script was executed.

Comment: The task of js file is already fixed when it loads in home page. . By the time user reaches to sensitive page, the events are triggered by cached js file. Complex requirement :(  we cant unload a cached js. So that's why I am trying to unregister event listeners by checking js file name. Is is possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by "cached"? Just don't include the `<script src=…>` tag in the sensitive page, and it won't load (either from cache or elsewhere).

Comment: And as I said before, if you want to try to unregister event listeners you have to tell us more about that script (like, actual code, api docs of the analytics third party). Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I am not loading in sensitive page. We dont have any API kind of thing from third party JS. Our site is a Single Page Application. The functionality of Third party JS for all pages is already fixed before loading into browser as per configuration. I can't share code. I am able to delete event listener in Chrome developer tool. Is it possible for us through code ?

Comment: No, it's hardly possible then (and surely we cannot advise anything without seeing code). Talk to the guys who fixed the third party js into all pages.